# Android : Set current item on GridViewPager

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-gridview

I can't set the current item in a Grid View Pager. Here is my code :

```
public class GridActivity extends Activity {

private GridAdapter GridAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);

    final Resources res = getResources();
    final GridViewPager pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    GridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, getFragmentManager());

    pager.setAdapter(GridAdapter);

    pager.setCurrentItem(0, 1);

    DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
    dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);

    };

}
```

Adapter class

```
public class GridAdapter extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private List <Row> mRows;

    public GridAdapter(Context ctx, FragmentManager fm, DataMap dm) {

        super(fm);
        mContext = ctx;

        mRows = new ArrayList <Row>();

        Row row = new Row();

        int position = 0;

        for(DataMap attendee : dm.getDataMapArrayList("array")) {
            AFragment af = new AFragment();
            dm.putInt("tag", position);
            af.setArguments(dm.toBundle());

            row.add(af);
            position++;
        }

        mRows.add(row);

    }


    private Fragment cardFragment(int titleRes, int textRes) {
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        CardFragment fragment =
                CardFragment.create(res.getText(titleRes), res.getText(textRes));
        // Add some extra bottom margin to leave room for the page indicator
        fragment.setCardMarginBottom(
                res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_margin_bottom));
        return fragment;
    }

    private class Row {

        final List<Fragment> columns = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        public Row(Fragment... fragments) {
            for (Fragment f : fragments) {
                add(f);
            }
        }

        public void add(Fragment f) {
            columns.add(f);
        }

        Fragment getColumn(int i) {
            return columns.get(i);
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getFragment(int row, int col) {
        Row adapterRow = mRows.get(row);
        return adapterRow.getColumn(col);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return mRows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(int rowNum) {
        return mRows.get(rowNum).getColumnCount();
    }

    }
```

I am setting the current item on the pager but it is not working, it starts always on the first page.

Comment: pls attach ur adapter class.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround like this after setting the adapter :

```
    pager.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(0, position, false);
            pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            pager.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        }
    });
```